# Celsius to Fahrenheit Loop with user input

Tags: java

I need to create a program that will output a formatted two column list converting Celsius to Fahrenheit ending at the temperature 40 degrees from the starting temperature, which is entered by the user. It's supposed to look like this: (except it counts up from whatever the user enters as Celsius)

[image: Conversion Chart]

I've been working at this for hours and I have no idea how to fix it. Not only is the Celsius starting at 1 (which I think is that (cel=1;) bit), but I have no idea why Fahrenheit is not calculating correctly.

Here's my current source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        float cel;
        double column;
        double Fahrenheit;
        final double C_2_F = (9.0 / 5.0);
        System.out.println("Enter your city's temperature in Celsius.");
        cel = kb.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Here is the conversion from " + cel);
        System.out.printf("%2s%12s%n", "Celcius", "Fahrenheit");
        for (cel = 1; cel <= 10; cel++) {
            column = cel;
            for (Fahrenheit = 1; Fahrenheit <= 10; Fahrenheit++) {
                Fahrenheit = cel * C_2_F + 32;
                System.out.printf("%2.0f%12.0f%n", cel, Fahrenheit);
            }
        }
        kb.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I formatted your code, I fixed a syntax error and removed a warning by adding the kb.close() method.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your loop to not reset 'Fahrenheit' each time through.

```
for ( Fahrenheit = 1; Fahrenheit <=10; Fahrenheit++) { 
    Fahrenheit = cel * C_2_F + 32;
    System.out.printf("%2.0f%12.0f%n",cel,Fahrenheit);
}
```

To

```
for ( Fahrenheit = 1; Fahrenheit <=10; Fahrenheit++) { 
    double f = cel * C_2_F + 32;
    System.out.printf("%2.0f%12.0f%n",cel,f);
}
```

Would be one way. Also rename 'Fahrenheit' to 'fahrenheit'

Actually, that's only one issue. That's just going to print out the same value 10 times since 'cel' and 'C_2_F' don't change during the loop...

Comment: Do you know how I would get the values to change based on the user input? As for the formula, should I establish the conversion another way?

Comment: Sorry, not going to do your homework, but you read `cel` from the user and then completely ignore it by using `for (cel = 1; cel <= 10; cel++)`

Comment: I'm not asking you to do my homework, I'm asking for help because I've been trying to figure this out for 6 hours now and I'm at my wits end. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I don't know what to put in cel = 1; to make it read from user input. Literally no idea. Can you point to something that could teach me what to do if you're unwilling to assist?

Comment: Ask you tutor or read aloud what the for loop is doing. It sets cel to 1 (overwriting your user input). Keeps looping while cel < 10. Adds 1 to cel each time through. What you want is something like "Start at cel. Keep looping while <something> is less than cel + 40. Add 1 each time through"